# Return resource in a specific pattern

Tags: php, laravel, resources

I am trying to make my resource return the data in this way `(1) 2020-11-26 / 2020-11-27 (id) data_from / data_to` is there any way to do that?

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    $parent_array = parent::toArray($request);

    $return_array = [];
    $return_array['id'] = $parent_array['id'];
    $return_array['text'] = $parent_array['data_from'];
    $return_array['text2'] = $parent_array['data_to'];

    return $return_array;
}
```

```json
{
    "response": {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "2020-11-26",
        "text2": "2020-11-27"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use basic [string concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)?

Answer (score 0):

```
return sprintf('(%s) %s / %s', $parent_array['id'], $parent_array['data_from'], $parent_array['data_to']);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Basic concatenation of the string elements would work too `$string1 . ' ' . $string2`.

But not sure if you want the existing values as well.

What ever is receiving the data could also format it as a string

Comment: Please help to close basic duplicate questions in 2022.  We already have at least 5 pages for all basic questions.  The time has come to consolidate the content on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i solved using  $return_array['text'] = "($id) " . $this->data_from->format('Y-m-d') . " / " . $this->data_to->format('Y-m-d');